# Python Openposeにてスケルトンだけの画像を出す方法はありますか

Tags: python

GithubのIssuesを探りましたが、ドキュメンテーションを読んでくれとクリエイターのコメントが残ってるだけで読んだ限り、スケルトンのJsonファイルを出すことはできると思いますが、これを基にどうすればスケルトンだけが動いている動画を作成できるか知りたいです。

例としてはこちらのデモ動画の最初の数秒間です。
[デモ](https://github.com/michalfaber/keras_Realtime_Multi-Person_Pose_Estimation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github Issuesにて回答が有りましたが、`--disable_blending`のフラッグが必要です。

以下はOpenPose Colabにて実行する時のコマンドですが、参考になると思います。

```
cd openpose && ./build/examples/openpose/openpose.bin --video ../video.mp4 --write_json ./output/ --display 0  --write_video ../openpose-skeleton.avi --disable_blending
```